# Filtering a dataframe, but can't access the number in a pandas series

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, filter

I am trying to filter a DataFrame, and add values to a list if they meet certain criteria.

```
list.append( df['Sum of Hours'][(df['Class'] == condition_a) & (df['Name'] == condition_b)] )
```

The problem I'm getting is I end up appending <class 'pandas.core.series.Series'> to my list, rather than the  value itself.  So I get a collection of entries like this in my list:

```
0    32.0
Name: Sum of Hours, dtype: float64
```

whereas I really just want the number '32.0'.  Advice on how to extract the number would be appreciated.

Comment: Just do: df['Sum of Hours'][(df['Class'] == condition_a) & (df['Name'] == condition_b)].at[0, 'Sum of Hours']`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can access the values with `.at`

```py
list_.append( df['Sum of Hours'][(df['Class'] == condition_a) & (df['Name'] == condition_b)].at[0, 'Sum of Hours'] )
```

- **Note**: Avoid using Python built-in names `list` as a variable. I have renamed yours to `list_`.